# How to implement the accent/diacritic insensitive search in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, icu

This question is related to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779853/how-to-implement-the-accent-diacritic-insensitive-search-in-sqlite), but I couldn't figure out the answer.

I have enabled the ICU support in SQLite and rebuild the Db Engine, now what? I have checked the ICU support by executing SELECT UPPER("ä") which results in Ä.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18

> (18) Case-insensitive matching of Unicode characters does not work.

```
The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive comparisons of ASCII
characters. The reason for this is that doing full Unicode case-insensitive comparisons
and case conversions requires tables and logic that would nearly double the size of the
SQLite library. The SQLite developers reason that any application that needs full Unicode
case support probably already has the necessary tables and functions and so SQLite should
not take up space to duplicate this ability.

Instead of providing full Unicode case support by default, SQLite provides the ability to
link against external Unicode comparison and conversion routines. The application can
overload the built-in NOCASE collating sequence (using sqlite3_create_collation()) and
the built-in like(), upper(), and lower() functions (using sqlite3_create_function()).
The SQLite source code includes an "ICU" extension that does these overloads. Or,
developers can write their own overloads based on their own Unicode-aware comparison
routines already contained within their project.
```

Comment: OP says he/she already uses the ICU extension, which provides those overloads. Now what?